# Reading a file and writing it backwards

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#input
inPut = input("Please enter a file name: ")
outPut = input("Please enter a file name which you would like the file reversed: ")

#open
infile = open(inPut, "r")
outfile = open(outPut, "w")

#list main file

line = infile.readline()
line = line.rstrip()
while line != "" :
    print(line)
    line = infile.readline()
    line = line.rstrip()

#output file in reversed
outfile.write(
####confused here######




#close files
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

So i've been trying to figure this out, i found this code in the book below which is suppose to list a file backwards. Im confused how i can apply that to my code. My main goal is to write a program that reads each line in the file, then reverses its lines and writes them to another file.

```
for line in reversed(list(open("filename"))):
        print(line.rstrip())
```

Comment: Are you trying to reverse the order of lines as your code suggests, or the lines themselves as your description suggests, or the entire file as the title suggests?

Answer (score 0):

`reversed()` will return to you a copy of the data you give it, but the order reversed.

When you call `open(filename)` you get back a file object that gives you lines from the file.  `list()` makes a list of those.  `reversed()` then gives you lines from the list, in reverse order.

If you want to reverse a line, you will need to do something like this:

```
s = reversed(line)
```

But `s` won't be a string.  It will be an iterator, and each time you iterate it, you will get back one character.  What you need is a way to join these characters back into a string.

So you can use `str.join()`, which knows how to use an iterator.  You should simply use an empty string as the separator between joined characters:

```
s = ''.join(reversed(line))
```

So now you just need a way to get lines from a file, and a way to write out the changes.  Here's the best way to do it:

```
in_name = "some_input_file_name.txt"
out_name = "some_output_file_name.txt"
with open(in_name, "rt") as in_f, open(out_name, "wt") as out_f:
    for line in in_f:
        line = line.strip()
        reversed_line = ''.join(reversed(line))
        out_f.write(reversed_line + "\n")
```

So just modify the above to let the user type in the file names, and I think you will have what you wanted to have.

If you want to learn more about iterators, here is a good place to start:  http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/functional.html#iterators

Good luck and have fun!